# Without learning "java spring" framework, it is hard to create complicated or high-level web site?

Tags: spring, jsp

I'm junior in university.
And I have studied in computer-science and engineering for over 4~5 years.
Now I'm interested in and studying "jsp, javascript. html5, css3" so called "web programming"

My question is as title, It needs to learn "java spring" framework to create web site.
That is, it is not sufficient only jsp(+javascript, html5, css3 as well) to create web site.

Comment: The answers you get will tend to be biased, but anyways: JSP+JS+HTML5+CSS is sufficient. Spring Framework will help you do many things easier in a shorter period of time. but this is nothing that you learn in a few days. Have a look at http://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ and the other guides.

Comment: I would go on saying that when you are talking about development in Spring, the presumption is made that project is or in future going to be complex. For such a complex project, one needs html,css,javascript as well as java, database, security, etc. But such projects are handled by a team. One person does not generally do it all and is not even recommended given that each developer has speciality like backend, frontend, etc. So, you have to decide what you like, first learn that, then stuff around it. Eg : If you interested in backend, learn java, then spring, database, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Like all political but correct answers, it **depends**. First of all, it is important and the core of the answer to your question, to note that you **can** make a web site **without** using **Spring**. However, as time progresses and your needs change, you can want to build more complex things and Spring comes to help you. There are a lot of beautiful features and solutions of Spring which I don't want to explicitly list all of them. In this context, it can be said that "**Why reinvent the wheel**?" Here are things that why you should not reinvent wheel:

1) **Spring Security**: If you don't want security to be pain in the head, you can make use of Spring security.

2) **Spring autowired beans**: If you need to connect beans, you can make use autowired property of Spring.

As I said earlier, I don't want to explicitly list all of them, but these two things are highly probable ones that you may need in the future.

My suggestion is, do your project with the technologies you have written. As time passes, list the things that you wish they have already been written for you. If Spring suits for these needs, it probably will, then start to learn Spring.